# Как корректно написать страницу ошибки (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я хочу в своем проекте реализовать то, что если допустим будет неправильно введен URl то должна выскочить JSP страница со словами- "ошибка 404 страница не найдена"

Я написал код но он неправильный. Надо чтобы просто выскакивала страница со словами об ошибке

WEB XML

```
<error-page>
    <location>/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

ErrorController

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        ModelAndView errorPage = new ModelAndView("errorPage");
        String errorMsg = "";
        int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);

        switch (httpErrorCode) {
            case 400: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 400. Bad Request";
                break;
            }
            case 401: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 401. Unauthorized";
                break;
            }
            case 404: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
                break;
            }
            case 500: {
                errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 500. Internal Server Error";
                break;
            }
        }
        errorPage.addObject("errorMsg", errorMsg);
        return errorPage;
    }

    private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return (Integer) httpRequest
          .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

    }
@RequestMapping(value = "500Error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void throwRuntimeException() {
    throw new NullPointerException("Throwing a null pointer exception");
}
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${errorMsg}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Как можно исправить код чтобы просто выскакивала вот такая страница

```
<%@ page contentType='text/html; charset=UTF-8' %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Страница не найдена</title>
    </head>
    <body>        

                    <p>
                        Запрашиваемая страница не найдена
                    </p>                

        </table>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: в jsp для этого есть тэг errorPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так. Хотя в спринге может что и получше придумано.

web.xml

```
<web-app>  
 <error-page>  
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>  // - по типу исключения
  <error-code>404</error-code> // - или по коду ошибки
  <location>/error.jsp</location>  
  </error-page>  
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
 <%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %> 
    <form action="doesnotexist.jsp">  
         <input type="submit" value="s"/>  
    </form>
```

error.jsp

```
Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен. Но кажется вам вот тут нужно изменить, на ваше `Запрашиваемая страница не найдена`

```java
case 404: {
    errorMsg = "Http Error Code: 404. Resource not found";
    break;
}
```